# CloudWatch Insights query: Format a DateTime string for grouping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have json-formatted CloudWatch logs whose entries resemble this:

```
{
    "message": "resource_liked",
    "context": {
        "date": {
            "date": "2021-05-07 16:52:11.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
    ...
```

I am trying to write a CloudWatch insights query to make a simple histogram: number of events in the log per hour.

However, I can't use the `@timestamp` attribute of the log entry. I need to use `context.date.date` in the entry's message body instead.

Writing this query using `@timestamp` is simple enough:

```
stats count(*) by datefloor(@timestamp, 1h)
```

However, I'm not sure how I can use the message's `context.date.date` instead.

I assume I need to format the dateimes that look like `2021-05-07 16:52:11.000000` into something that aws understands as a datetime, but I can't find how.

---

#### What I've tried so far

`stats count(*) by datefloor(context.date.date, 1h)` -> "Invalid Date"

`stats count(*) by datefloor(toMillis(context.date.date), 1h)` -> "Invalid Date"

`stats count(*) by datefloor(substr(context.date.date, 0, 19), 1h)` -> "Invalid Date"

`stats count(*) by datefloor(concat(replace(substr(context.date.date, 0, 23), ' ', 'T'), '-00:00'), 1h)` -> Invalid Date. This one makes the field look exactly like how @timestamp is displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
| parse @message '"date": "*:' as hour
| stats count() as cnt by hour
```

[Parsing a timestamp to use with CW Log Insights functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837992/parsing-a-timestamp-to-use-with-cw-log-insights-functions#comment112932213_60837992)

Answer (score 6):

Might help to convert the string datetime to  numerical milliseconds, note that max year is 2100 due to leap year computation.

```
fields "2021-05-07 16:52:11.000000" as reqDateTime
| parse reqDateTime "*-*-* *:*:*.*" as reqYear, reqM, reqD, reqH, reqMin, reqSec, reqMilliSec
| fields reqYear - 1970 as reqYearDiff, reqYear % 4 == 0 as reqIsLeapYear, reqM/1 as reqMonth, reqD/1 as reqDay, reqH/1 as reqHour, reqMin/1 as reqMinute, reqSec/1 as reqSecond, reqMilliSec/1 as reqMilliSecond
| fields ((reqYearDiff * 365) + ((reqYear % 4 == 1) * 1) + floor(reqYearDiff / 4) # as yearsToDays
         + ((reqMonth == 2) * 31) # 
         + ((reqMonth == 3) * 59) #
         + ((reqMonth == 4) * 90) #
         + ((reqMonth == 5) * 120) #
         + ((reqMonth == 6) * 151) #
         + ((reqMonth == 7) * 181) #
         + ((reqMonth == 8) * 212) #
         + ((reqMonth == 9) * 243) #
         + ((reqMonth == 10) * 273) #
         + ((reqMonth == 11) * 304) #
         + ((reqMonth == 12) * 334) #
         + ((reqMonth > 2) and (reqIsLeapYear == 1)) # as monthsToDays
         + reqDay - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 # as daysToMilliSeconds
         + reqHour * 60 * 60 * 1000 # as hoursToMilliSeconds
         + reqMinute * 60 * 1000 # as minutesToMilliSeconds
         + reqSecond * 1000 # as secondsToMilliSeconds
         + reqMilliSecond  
         as reqMilliSeconds
| display reqMilliSeconds, fromMillis(reqMilliSeconds), reqYear, reqMonth, reqDay, reqHour, reqMinute, reqSecond, reqMilliSecond
| limit 1
```

Comment: wow! nicely done. Only if they supported functions

Comment: Excellent answer, sorry I can't upvote more than once!

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  Unbelievable that AWS can't provide this as a built in function but it was a total life saver.  If you're ever in Canberra Australia hit me up and I'll buy you a beer 

Answer (score 0):

I quited liked the `datefloor` approach proposed by @amacrobert, so I tried it out and it does work with a tweak

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| filter @message like /Whatever/
| sort @timestamp desc
| stats count() as log_count by datefloor(@timestamp, 1h) as date_to_hour
| display date_to_hour, log_count
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply parse the date as you require

like this

```
| parse '"date": "* *:*:*",' as date, hour, minutes, seconds
| fields concat(date," ",hour,"h") as hourly
| stats count(*) as counted by hourly
```