# Format the way I see AWS Cloudwatch timestamps in Log Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Is there a way to show the timestamps in cloudwatch in a friendlier format?
If we take a super simple query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 200
```

I get the standard @timestamp column to show:

```
2022-03-15T13:38:15.567+00:00
```

Can I have something simple like:

```
13:38:15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using formatting on the timestamp field like in this post.

[CloudWatch Insights query: Format a DateTime string for grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67441302/cloudwatch-insights-query-format-a-datetime-string-for-grouping)

Comment: thank's using a datefloor(@timestamp, 1s) does help a lot with readability

Answer (score 1):

Although using datefloor(@timestamp, 1s) helps a lot with readability, unfortunately the official answer is:

> Currently, CloudWatch Logs Insights doesn't support filtering logs with human readable timestamps.

Taken from the documentation found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html